# Clean URL notworking properly (With Virtualmin)

Tags: 8

Some times, for some links/pages of my Drupal 8 site **/index.php/en** appears instead of **/en**. Currently I'm using **Virtualmin**, I haven't this behavior before use this virtualmin admin panel.

Thank you for your help.